# Sorting dates in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, datetime, datagridview

I'm pulling different info from a SQL table using sqlDataReader.
One of the columns contains DateTime, and is pulled from the sql and displayed correctly, using:

```
var datestring = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("deadline")).ToShortDateString();
```

It is shown in the DataGridView in the following format: `dd.MM.yyyy`

When I try to sort this, it sorts it after `dd`, no matter what the `MM` and `yyyy` info is.

The datestring is put in the datagridview with the following command:

```
dgv_tasks.Rows.Add(tid, taskname, sidvariable, datestring);
```

Anyone knows why it's not sorting this as dates at all, just the number in `dd` ?

(I've looked here for an answer, but none of the similar questions had a working answer).

Comment: How do you sort your datagridview exactly? Looks like you sorting it based on a `string`, note a `DateTime`.

Comment: Can you not sort it via your SQL query?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You want to leave it as a `DateTime` in the `DataGridView`, not convert it to a string. That's why it's sorting alphabetically, instead of by date.

Remove `.ToShortDateString()` and define your `DataGridViewColumn` as a `DateTime` type (assuming you're creating the columns manually).

After assigning the data to the `DataGridView`, just modify that column's `DefaultCellStyle.Format` value to display the date in whatever you manner you choose:

```
dgv_tasks.Columns["deadline"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd.MM.yyyy";
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly! :)

Answer (score 2):

It's sorting alphabetically because you converted it to a string.

Try using the date value in your datagridview with a formatter for displaying purposes.